# Summatory function of Euler-phi

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, multiplicative-function, mobius-inversion

Let $F(n) = \sum_{d^2|n} \phi(d)$. We must show that if $F(1) = 1$, and if $n>1$ factors as $n=p^{a_1}_1p^{a_2}_2...p^{a_m}_m$, then
$$
F(n)=\prod_{i=1}^{m} p^{[a_i/2]}_i.
$$
If I understood correctly, we must first use Mobius inversion to get
$
\sum_{d^2|n}  \phi(d) = \sum_{\sigma |n} g(\sigma)
$
, where

$
g(\delta) = f(d) = f(\sqrt{\delta})
$
.
But I'm confused about what follows after that.

Comment: Have you done the case when $n=p_1^{a_1}$ with no other prime factors?

Comment: Hint: figure out what integer $m$ (in terms of $n$) has the property that $\sum_{d^2\mid n} g(d) = \sum_{d\mid m} g(d)$ for any function $g(d)$.